# How can I prevent vertex groups from affecting both sides of a Mirrored model?

Tags: faces, vertex-groups

I'm working with a rigged model that I've cut in half with the intention of using Mirror/Symmetrize. I've added some additional finger bones to the model and given them weights and vertex groups.

What I'm noticing is that when I go to Mirror the model, the vertex groups on the bones that I've added are affecting both sides of the model (e.g, when I select the left finger vertex group, both the left AND the equivalent right-side faces are selected, instead of just the left). This is happening regardless of whether I've checked Vertex Groups in the Mirror modifier settings.

Is there a way to make sure that the left finger vertex groups only affect the left finger, or do I need to apply the Mirror and manually remove the affected right-side vertices from the left vertex group?

Comment: You need to have both a finger.L group (with vertices assigned) and a finger.R group (with no vertices assigned.)  And the mirror modifier needs to be higher (evaluated prior to) the armature modifier.

Comment: I've got all of that exactly as you say, but it's still associating the right vertices with the left vertex group.

Comment: Never mind, I got it working. Thanks for your suggestion! I did as you said and it wasn't working, but I had to actually apply the Mirror modifier to see the effects.

Comment: if you had to apply the mirror modifier, it probably wasn't being evaluated in the proper order.  The mirror modifier needs to be, literally, closer to the top of the screen than the armature modifier.  That makes it get evaluated first.

Comment: Right, that's where it was - the very first modifier, of which there were only two, with the other being Armature. But if I enable the edit cage on the Mirror modifier and select the .L vertex group, it will still highlight both sides. But once I apply it, the .R takes over.

Comment: Yeah, the edit cage is not really wholly accurate.  Notice that if you enable the edit cage on the mirror mod, it's actually selecting both sides of any particular vert, and showing you the vertex groups for the unmirrored side.  But try dropping into weight paint and look at your groups, or just try posing your armature.